# Как выбрать уникальные пары значений в Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, orm, django-orm

Мне нужно выбрать уникальыне пары значений из модели, для этого я пытаюсь сделать так:

```py
brand_model_variants = qs.values_list('brand', 'model').distinct()
brand_model_variants = qs.values_list('brand', 'model').distinct('brand', 'model')
```

Оба этих варианта не рабочие, потому что первый выдает неуникальные значения, а второй ругается на то, что я использую аннотации:

> annotate() + distinct(fields) is not implemented.

Можно ли как-то это обойти, кроме последующего удаления дублей питоном?

Comment: По какому критерию выбирать уникальные записи?

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 уникальные записи - в смысле уникальные сочетания бренда и модели, которые встречаются среди фильтруемых записей.

Comment: Посмотрите ответ

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен, что правильно понял задачу. Но вот, попробуйте как-то так.

```
brand_model_variants = qs.values('brand', 'model').distinct()
```

Также посмотрите этот [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33104968/12884304).

Comment: В принципе, рабочий вариант. Жаль только, что пары возвращаются как словари, но не критично

Comment: Не, поторопился с выводми. Ваш вариант также как и мой выводит все сочетания, но они не уникальны. Если сочетание 'brand', 'model' повторится, он повторит его несколько раз.

Comment: что касается ответа по ссылке - я не могу так сделать. Мне важен порядок, который уже задан в `qs` и мне нужно выбрать значения именно в том порядке, в котором они следуют в выборке, но только уникальные.